# Numeric Notify Icon Windows Forms 1..2..3

Tags: winforms, notifyicon

I need to create a Numeric NotifyIcon which should show the data in Percentage.
like when minimized it should show 1% then 2% say after a gap of 5 seconds and so on.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [showing animated NotifyIcon](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2005/09/12/animation-and-text-in-system-tray-using-c.aspx)